# Google Sheets row to array

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, flatten, textjoin

I need to create an array out of google sheets columns:

| product | feature_a | feature_b | feature_c | Array |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ["feature_a","feature_b","feature_c",] |
| p2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ["feature_b",] |
| p3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ["feature_a",] |
| p4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | [] |

Currently my formula is

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A2:A);"";"[" & if(B2:B = 1; concatenate(char(34);$B$1; char(34);char(44));"") & if(C2:C = 1; concatenate(char(34);$C$1; char(34);char(44));"") & if(D2:D = 1; concatenate(char(34);$D$1; char(34);char(44));"") & "]"))
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this, esp. without referencing each column individually? My original sheet has much more columns.

Google sheet:
[image]

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster btw, (yes I am aware that its naive to expect some reason from mods) but did you try to raise the awareness of this google sheets security issue with them and demand some immediate action (like maybe some popup box with your message whenever the user enters google sheets URL into the question box or something) ...nah, scratch that, mods are programmed not to care about important stuff...

Comment: @player0 I'm sure mods cannot do that without help from company staff. Furthermore, it'll require massive consensus from all parties involved(But I'm the solo crusader here).

Comment: @player0 took me a bit to understand what your formula is doing. But, great solution - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="";;"["&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:D=1; """"&B1:D1&""""; ));;9^9))); " "; ",")&"]"))
```

[image]